# TypeScript: cannot use variable to reference a string when constructing a type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to type my action. Here is the code.

```
type Increment = {
  type: 'INCREMENT'
  payload: number
}

const action: Increment = {
  type: 'INCREMENT',
  payload: 1
}

console.log(action);
```

Then I wanted to extract `'INCREMENT'` into its own variable so I can use it in multiple places. So I did this

```
const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'

type Increment = {
  type: INCREMENT
  payload: number
}

const action: Increment = {
  type: 'INCREMENT',
  payload: 1
}

console.log(action);
```

However the TS compiler is yelling at me and says

> 'INCREMENT' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did
> you mean 'typeof INCREMENT'?

so I had to add `typeof` in front of `INCREMENT` to make it happy, as in

```
type Increment = {
  type: typeof INCREMENT
  payload: number
}
```

I don't understand why is that when I am using a variable to reference the string suddenly the breaks the rule. Also shouldn't `typeof INCREMENT` be a string `string`. I thought it would be equivalent to `type: string` but apparently here I cannot assign `type` with anything string other than `INCREMENT`. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you were using a TypeScript feature called [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) which allow you to specify the exact value a string type variable can have. In this case the property `type` can only have the string value `INCREMENT`.

```
type Increment = {
  type: 'INCREMENT'
  payload: number
}
```

When you assigned that string literal to a variable using `const`, TypeScript no longer recognizes it as a type but as an actual value. Hence the error message `'INCREMENT' refers to a value...`.

If you assign that literal to a `type` variable that would work, as TypeScipt will see that as a type and not a value.

```
type INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
type Increment = {
  type: INCREMENT
  payload: number
};
```

However, you won't be able to "reuse" the actual string literal as a value it in multiple places.

One other solution I would recommend is using [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums). For example:

```
enum IncrementType {
  INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT',
  DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT' // Added this just as an example
}

type Increment = {
  type: IncrementTypes
  payload: number
}

const action: Increment = {
  type: IncrementType.INCREMENT,
  payload: 1
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I remember in JS `typeof INCREMENT` would just return `string`. but in TS it would return the actual exact value a string has i.e. `'INCREMENT'`?

Comment: No worries. As far as I'm aware of, the `typeof` operator behaves the same way in TS as it does in JS.

Comment: then in that case. should `typeof` always returns `string` instead of the specific exact value?

Comment: @Joji Yes, I believe that `typeof` will always return `string`. The TS docs say this about typeof:

"These typeof type guards are recognized in two different forms: typeof v === `typename` and typeof v !== `typename`, where `typename` must be `number`, `string`, `boolean`, or `symbol`."

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards

Answer (score 0):

Try this: instead of const define new type

```
type INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'

type Increment = {
  type: INCREMENT
  payload: number
}

const action: Increment = {
  type: 'INCREMENT',
  payload: 1
}

console.log(action);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because with `const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'` you have a `string` *value* but you're using it to declare a type. That's why `typeof INCREMENT` works; that's a string literal so you get `type: "INCREMENT"` which is like a sub-type of `string` (it *is-a* `string`). However, [*it can only have a single value*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) of "INCREMENT". Like so:

```
const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'; // the apparent type is 'INCREMENT'
console.log(typeof INCREMENT); // the actual type is string

type Increment = {
  type: typeof INCREMENT,
  payload: number
}

const action: Increment = {
  type: INCREMENT,
  payload: 1
}
console.log(typeof action.type); // string
console.log(action.type); // INCREMENT
```

If you want use something like that in more than one place and will likely have more than one `type`. You can try an `enum`.

```
enum Type {
    INCREMENT = "INCREMENT",
    FOO = "FOO"
}

type Increment = {
  type: Type
  payload: number
}

const action: Increment = {
  type: Type.INCREMENT,
  payload: 1
}

console.log(action.type); // INCREMENT
```

Comment: "That's why typeof INCREMENT works; that's string so you get type: string." this is NOT true and this is exactly what I said in the question. If we were to get `type: string` as you said, we can assign any string to type later, but in fact we can only assign `"INCREMENT"` to it, not any other string value.

Comment: It actually is true tho I'll agree I did not clarify it enough; see the edits. @Joji